# SQL Server save brackets in nvarchar for Arabic language

Tags: sql-server, right-to-left, nvarchar

I am using sql server 2008 R2 to store my data. I have a datatable named postMaster where I save all the posts in my organization. All posts have to be described in english and arabic. My problem is with the arabic description of the post

My data table structure as follows:

[image]

and a sample record will look as follows:

[image]

As you can see from the picture, the Arabic description mixes up the brackets and when I display data in datagridview it would look the save way it is saved!

Is there away to make these brackets be properly saved as in english way?

Comment: sql server will store exactly what you give it (assuming correct collation)

Comment: I save data in the correct way but when you add write the brackets it immediately gets mixed! So its not the way it was added.

Comment: When I add the brackets in english all data keeps its own location based on input order, but in arabic it immediately gets mixed

Comment: What collation I should use for arabic?

Comment: perhaps a search engine might be useful?

Comment: I have noticed that if I add some text after the closing brackets not a space the brackets will be placed properly in the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the postDescAr is not displaying texts in a RTL format. The data is saved correctly, but not displayed correctly. It depends on from where you query the data.

Comment: This is right to display data from right to left but still the issue of the brackets is standing